# How to make an url pattern with a parameter supporting multiple types?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

If I have one variable being fetched from url pattern according to this regular expression:

```
re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uid>[\w]+)/?$', accounts.api.views.SetNewPassword.as_view()),
```

how to rewrite it to fetch few possible variables: either uid or u32id?

In url, there may be either u32id for links in old password recovery emails or plain uid in new recovery emails. But both must be supported in the view. So we will check kwargs for both of them anyway.

Comment: So multiple parameters or one of two options?

Comment: In url, there may be either u32id for links in old password recovery emails or plain uid in new recovery emails. But both must be supported in the view. So we will check kwargs for both of them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) to combine your `uuids`

```
from django.urls.converters import StringConverter, UUIDConverter

class MyCustomPathConverter(UUIDConverter):
   regex = 'regex_of_uuid|regex_of_u32id'  # '|' is mandatory to distinguish multiple regex 

   def to_python(self, value):
        return value

   def to_url(self, value):
        return value
```

#### urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, register_converter 
register_converter(MyCustomPathConverter, 'my_uuid_converter')

path('reset/<my_uuid_converter:uid>/', accounts.api.views.SetNewPassword.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make several trivial patterns mapped to the same view ordered from more specific to less specific:

```
path('reset/<uuid:uid>/', accounts.api.views.SetNewPassword.as_view()),
path('reset/<int:id>/', accounts.api.views.SetNewPassword.as_view()),
...
```

Comment: And how will one or the other route be selected, in my opinion they are the same in terms of the url-matching?

Comment: `uuid` and `int` patterns are not the same at all. You tried to build such patterns manually whilst there are built-in patterns like these two.